# Как вычислить случайный вектор между двумя зонами?

Tags: c#, unity3d

2Д игра. Условно, вокруг игрока два квадрата. Между квадратов(в зеленой зоне), в случайных позициях должны спавниться враги. (См. схему)

[image: схема]

Моя задумка: Создаю 2 массива по 4 вектора в каждом, вместе они образуют 2 квадрата. Получается то же, что и на схеме. Мне нужно в этой области получать случайный вектор, чтобы на нём спавнить врага.  Как это сделать - не пойму. Возможно это вообще не по такой системе считается. Прошу помощи. Спасибо.

```
public List<Vector3> zoneOne = new List<Vector3>(4);
public List<Vector3> zoneTwo = new List<Vector3>(4);
  
private void Update()
{
   RandomPosSpawnAround(10, 15);
}

public void RandomPosSpawnAround(float minRadius, float maxRadius)
    {
        zoneOne = new List<Vector3>(4);
        zoneTwo = new List<Vector3>(4);

        Vector3 pos;

        if (player != null) pos = player.transform.position;
        else return;

        zoneOne.Add(new Vector3(pos.x + minRadius, pos.y + minRadius));
        zoneOne.Add(new Vector3(pos.x + minRadius, pos.y - minRadius));
        zoneOne.Add(new Vector3(pos.x - minRadius, pos.y - minRadius));
        zoneOne.Add(new Vector3(pos.x - minRadius, pos.y + minRadius));

        zoneTwo.Add(new Vector3(pos.x + maxRadius, pos.y + maxRadius));
        zoneTwo.Add(new Vector3(pos.x + maxRadius, pos.y - maxRadius));
        zoneTwo.Add(new Vector3(pos.x - maxRadius, pos.y - maxRadius));
        zoneTwo.Add(new Vector3(pos.x - maxRadius, pos.y + maxRadius));

        //этот код просто для визуальной отрисовки зон
        Debug.DrawLine(zoneOne[0], zoneOne[1], Color.green);
        Debug.DrawLine(zoneOne[1], zoneOne[2], Color.blue);
        Debug.DrawLine(zoneOne[2], zoneOne[3], Color.yellow);
        Debug.DrawLine(zoneOne[3], zoneOne[0], Color.cyan);

        Debug.DrawLine(zoneTwo[0], zoneTwo[1], Color.green);
        Debug.DrawLine(zoneTwo[1], zoneTwo[2], Color.blue);
        Debug.DrawLine(zoneTwo[2], zoneTwo[3], Color.yellow);
        Debug.DrawLine(zoneTwo[3], zoneTwo[0], Color.cyan);

    }
```

P.S пробовал ещё такой способ. Только спавняться в верхнем правом углу. Не знаю как зарандомить:

```
public void RandomPos()
    {
        float minRadius = 10;
        float maxRadius = 15;

        Vector3 playerPos;
        Vector3 randomSpawnPos;

        if (player != null) playerPos = player.transform.position;
        else return;

        float randX = Random.Range(playerPos.x + minRadius, playerPos.x + maxRadius);
        float randY = Random.Range(playerPos.y + minRadius, playerPos.y + maxRadius);

        if (Random.Range(0, 1) == 0) randomSpawnPos = new Vector3(randX, randY);
        else randomSpawnPos = new Vector3(-randX, -randY);

        Instantiate(enemyPf, randomSpawnPos, Quaternion.identity);

    }
```

Comment: Как вариант - определить минимальную и максимальную дистанцию от персонажа и спавнить врагов на основании этой дистанции.

Comment: @KOTlK Не совсем понял. Методу `Instantiate()` нужен вектор, в какой точке спавнить. А как мне к вектору игрока прибавить(или умножить) случайный вектор с учётом минимальной и максимальной дистанции?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Приведу пример.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Debug.DrawRay(GetRandomPositionAroundPlayer(transform.position, 20, 10), Vector2.up, Color.red, 100f);
        }
    }


    private Vector2 GetRandomPositionAroundPlayer(Vector2 playerPosition, float spawnRadius, float safeDistance)
    {
        if (spawnRadius <= safeDistance) throw new Exception("Spawn radius can't be lower safe distance");

        var randomPoint = playerPosition + UnityEngine.Random.insideUnitCircle * spawnRadius;

        if (InsideArea(randomPoint, playerPosition, safeDistance)) 
            return GetRandomPositionAroundPlayer(playerPosition, spawnRadius, safeDistance);

        return randomPoint;
    }

    private bool InsideArea(Vector2 point, Vector2 playerPosition, float distanceAroundPlayer)
    {
        if (point.x < playerPosition.x + distanceAroundPlayer && point.y < playerPosition.y + distanceAroundPlayer)
        {
            if (point.x > playerPosition.x - distanceAroundPlayer && point.y > playerPosition.y - distanceAroundPlayer) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

`GetRandomPositionAroundPlayer`.

`spawnRadius` - дистанция от игрока, на которой могут спавниться враги. `safeDistance` - дистанция от игрока, на которой враги спавниться не могут.

В этом методе мы берем рандомную точку внутри круга с радиусом 1 (`Random.insideUnitCircle`) и умножаем на `spawnRadius`, чтобы увеличить этот самый радиус, далее прибавляем это все к позиции игрока, чтобы точка была относительно позиции игрока.

Далее передаем все данные в метод `InsideArea`. Если `InsideArea` возвращает `true`, то это означает, что точка входит в зону, где нельзя спавниться и мы вызываем метод `GetRandomPositionAroundPlayer`, иначе, просто возвращаем эту рандомную точку. Данный метод будет вызывать сам себя, до тех пор, пока точка будет находиться внутри безопасной области, поэтому мы выбрасываем исключение, если безопасная дистанция больше, чем радиус спавна.

Если вы навесите этот скрипт на любой объект, запустите игру и удержите пробел, то вокруг этого объекта в окне сцены будут появляться красные линии, которые демонстрируют где спавнятся эти точки.

Чтобы эти точки спавнились в квадрате, а не как сейчас, в круге, вам достаточно написать метод, который будет возвращать рандомную позицию внутри квадрата со стороной 1 и вставить его вместо `UnityEngine.Random.insideUnitCircle`. Думаю с этой задачей вы легко справитесь.

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ. Я и не догадался использовать `Random.insideUnitCircle`